# python statistical analysis

Tags: python, statistics

Given 15 players - 2 Goalkeepers, 5 defenders, 5 midfielders and 3 strikers, and the fact that each has a value and a score, I want to calculate the highest scoring team for the money I have. Each team must consist of 1 GK then a formation e.g. 4:4:2, 4:3:3 etc. I started with sample data such as this

player role points cost

I then did the following to evaluate all combinations

read each line into a list (for each role) then use itertools in a nested run to get all combinations

```
if line[1] == "G": G.append(line[0])
if line[1] == "D": D.append(line[0])
if line[1] == "M": M.append(line[0])
if line[1] == "S": S.append(line[0])

for gk in itertools.combinations(G,1):
    for de in itertools.combinations(D,4):
        for mi in itertools.combinations(M,4):
            for st in itertools.combinations(S,2):
                teams[str(count)]= " ".join(gk)+" "+" ".join(de)+" "+" ".join(mi)+" "+" ".join(st)
                count +=1
```

Having got the teams, I calculate their points value, and the team cost. If it's lower than the threshold, I print it.
But if I now make this 20 goalkeepers, 150 defenders, 150 midfielders and 100 strikers, I understandably get out of memory.
What could I do to perform this analysis? Is it a generator rather than a recursive function that I need?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to solve this problem with recursion. The following shows the basic outline, but ignores details like a team being composed of a certain number of certain types of players.

```
players=[{'name':'A','score':5,'cost':10},
         {'name':'B','score':10,'cost':3},
         {'name':'C','score':6,'cost':8}]

def player_cost(player):
    return player['cost']
def player_score(player):
    return player['score']
def total_score(players):
    return sum(player['score'] for player in players)

def finance_team_recurse(budget, available_players):
    affordable_players=[]
    for player in available_players:
        if player_cost(player)<=budget:
            # Since we've ordered available players, the first player appended
            # will be the one with the highest score.
            affordable_players.append(player)
    result=[]
    if affordable_players:
        candidate_player=affordable_players[0]
        other_players=affordable_players[1:]
        # if you include candidate_player on your team
        team_with_candidate=finance_team_recurse(budget-player_cost(candidate_player),
                                                 other_players)
        team_with_candidate.append(candidate_player)
        score_of_team_with_candidate=total_score(team_with_candidate)
        if score_of_team_with_candidate>total_score(other_players):
            result=team_with_candidate
        else:
            # if you exclude candidate_player from your team
            team_without_candidate=finance_team_recurse(budget, other_players)
            score_of_team_without_candidate=total_score(team_without_candidate)
            if score_of_team_with_candidate>score_of_team_without_candidate:
                result=team_with_candidate
            else:
                result=team_without_candidate
    return result

def finance_team(budget, available_players):
    tmp=available_players[:]
    # Sort so player with highest score is first. (Greedy algorithm?)
    tmp.sort(key=player_score, reverse=True)
    return finance_team_recurse(budget,tmp)

print(finance_team(20,players))
# [{'score': 6, 'cost': 8, 'name': 'C'}, {'score': 10, 'cost': 3, 'name': 'B'}]
```

---

```
20 choose 1 = 20 combinations
150 choose 4 = 20260275 combinations
100 choose 2 = 4950 combinations
```

So there are a total of 20*20260275*20260275*4950 = 40637395564486875000L
items in the `teams` dict. That takes a lot of memory.

```
for gk in itertools.combinations(G,1):
    for de in itertools.combinations(D,4):
        for mi in itertools.combinations(M,4):
            for st in itertools.combinations(S,2):    
                #Don't collect the results into a dict.
                #That's what's killing you (memory-wise).
                #Just compute the cost and
                #Just print the result here.
```

PS. 40637395564486875000L is on the order of `10**19`. Assuming your program can process `10**6` combinations per second, it will take about 1.3 millions years for the program to complete...

Comment: I a thousand years, the computers will be faster!

Comment: +1: Getting the combinatorics right.  This is a textbook example of computability **O** complexity and what not to do.  Brilliant.  Want to upvote this a lot more times.

Comment: @user317225: You really, really, really need to think about the overall complexity and essential computability before writing something like this.

Comment: @florin: In a thousand years your great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-great-granddaughter will need to update the script with new players. Of course, since she'll be using Python102.6 that will be easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Functions and generators help a lot:

```
def make_teams(G, D, M, S):
    """ returns all possible teams """
    for gk in itertools.combinations(G,1):
        for de in itertools.combinations(D,4):
            for mi in itertools.combinations(M,4):
                for st in itertools.combinations(S,2):
                    yield gk, de, mi, st

def get_cost( team ):
    return sum( member.cost for member in team )

def good_teams( min_score=0):
    for team in make_teams(G, D, M, S):
        if get_cost( team ) > min_score:
            yield team

for team in good_teams(min_score=100):
    print team
```

It still generates all possible combinations, so you'll probably run out of time now, instead of memory.

What you're doing seems like a variation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) - you can do better than try all possible combination, but not *much better*.

One way to get a good solution fast is to sort the players by their *score per money*. You should get the top scoring teams first, but there are no guarantees that you get the best possible solution. Wikipedia calls this the "Greedy approximation algorithm".

```
def score_per_cost( player ):
    return player.score / player.cost

def sorted_combinations(seq, n):
    return itertools.combinations(
        sorted(seq, key=score_per_cost, reverse=True),n)

def make_teams(G, D, M, S):
    """ returns all possible teams """
    for gk in sorted_combinations(G,1):
        for de in sorted_combinations(D,4):
            for mi in sorted_combinations(M,4):
                for st in sorted_combinations(S,2):
                    yield gk, de, mi, st

def get_cost( team ):
    return sum( member.cost for member in team )

def top_teams(n):
    return itertools.islice(make_teams(G, D, M, S),n)

for team in top_teams(100):
    print team
```

I'll leave adding the "cost per team < threshold" requirement to the reader (hint: it's one line in `make_teams` :p).

Comment: I was nearly sick when I looked at the knapsack problem!